# Making my XML looking good! Delphi :)

Tags: xml, delphi

Hey from the post request I get response a xml file.
eg.

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'#$D#$A'<PosXML version="6.0.2">'#$D#$A#9'<ShowInfoResponse>'#$D#$A#9#9'<ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>'#$D#$A#9'</ShowInfoResponse>'#$D#$A'</PosXML>'
```

Question is that how can I correct that, because I  need to send it to LoadXMLData('Here');

Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
xmldocument1:ixmldocument;
responseNode:ixmlnode;
test:string;
begin
xmldocument1 := loadxmldata('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'#$D#$A'<PsXML>'#$D#$A#9'<ShowInfo>'#$D#$A#9#9'<Code>1234</Code>'#$D#$A#9'</ShowInfo>'#$D#$A'</PsXML>');
responsenode := xmldocument1.DocumentElement.childnodes.Findnode('Code');
test := responsenode.ChildNodes[0].Text;
```

The problem is that test (string) always thows an exception becuase responsenode is nil.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your problem? Looks like valid xml at first glance.

Comment: XML is primary for data exchange between automated processes. Human readability is second. If you want to create a nice indented XML file you can use a tool for that.

Comment: The string he posted is indented nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're **incorrectly assuming** that there's something wrong with your XML.

The `DocumentElement` property gives you a reference to the `PsXML` or `PosXML` node. Reading the `ChildNodes` property of that gives you a list of that node's children. That list will consist of just one element, though, either a `ShowInfo` node or `ShowInfoResponse`. Calling `FindNode` on that list can only give you one of those values. **It does not search through the children of the nodes in the list.** Since the document element has no child `Code` element, `FindNode` correctly returns `nil`.

I suspect you're getting confused by the debugger. Your program has fetched something from the network, and you're storing that in a string. You're using the debugger to see what's in that string, and the debugger is showing you something with a bunch of number signs and dollar signs, which you're sure aren't supposed to be there. Your code isn't selecting the right node, so you conclude that the confusing XML string must be the cause.

But the XML is correct. And it's even pretty-printed already! It has line breaks and tab characters to indent things. But the debugger wants to show you a string that's unambiguous. If it showed an actual multiline string and indented things, then you as a programmer wouldn't know what was really in the string. Instead, the debugger shows you the numeric character codes of the characters that it can't display. Carriage returns and line feeds have numeric values 13 and 10, respectively, which in hexadecimal are D and A. The debugger uses Delphi's own string-literal format to show you the value; numeric character literals are introduced with a `#` symbol, followed by the character's numeric code. The `$` indicates the number is hexadecimal.

Answer (score 3):

To 'pretty print' XML code, you can use the Delphi function [FormatXMLData](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLDoc.FormatXMLData). LoadXMLData however does not give bonus points for human readability, so the original string would be ok.

Comment: The original string should *definitely* work OK since it's *already* formatted.

Answer (score 1):

This string works fine with LoadXMLData without changes.  Things like white space and carriage returns are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the wrong node, that's why it returns nil. You have to look for 'ReturnCode' instead of 'Code'.

Comment: His first example outside of his code example has "ReturnCode" his Code example however uses "Code".  Wow that sounds confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that Code is a Child node of ShowInfoResponse.  What about this:

```
responsenode := xmldocument1.DocumentElement.childnodes[0];
test := responsenode.ChildNodes['Code'].Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

IXMLNodeList.FindNode method looks for the search NodeName only on the nodes contained in the list, and not in the child nodes.

If what you want is to look at the entire tree, use this function:

```
function RecursiveFindNode(ANode: IXMLNode; const SearchNodeName: string): IXMLNode;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CompareText(ANode.NodeName, SearchNodeName) = 0 then
    Result := ANode
  else if not Assigned(ANode.ChildNodes) then
    Result := nil
  else begin
    for I := 0 to ANode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Result := RecursiveFindNode(ANode.ChildNodes[I], SearchNodeName);
      if Assigned(Result) then
        Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then, make something like this:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  ANode: IXMLNode;
begin
  xmldocument1 := loadxmldata('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'#$D#$A'<PsXML>'#$D#$A#9'<ShowInfo>'#$D#$A#9#9'<Code>1234</Code>'#$D#$A#9'</ShowInfo>'#$D#$A'</PsXML>');
  ANode := RecursiveFindNode(xmlDocument1.DocumentElement, 'Code');  //or ReturnCode if you use the first version of the XML
  if Assigned(ANode) then
    ShowMessage('Eureka!');
end;
```

**Warning**  Looking for nodes this way is very inefficient.  If you can anticipate the document structure, is better to use that knowledge to navigate the document and use the search only when needed.